# CSS Shift Downward

Tags: css

Can anyone tell me what is going on with this widget: http://davidbeckblog.com/notify/? The relevant CSS is mostly at the bottom of [style.css](http://davidbeckblog.com/wp-content/themes/ultimate/style.css).

Basically, the widget has 3 sections. On the left is the button, the middle is the text box, and the right is a spot for a progress indicator. When I add in the text box and the progress indicator, everything gets pushed down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are inline elements and the vertical align is `baseline` by default I believe. Set the vertical align on all 3 spans to `top`, and then it looks like you need to specify `margin-top:-3px` on span.status and maybe apply 1px top margin to the notify me span.

Alternatively you could have floated all 3 with a clearing element.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to fix it:

```
.notify-me input, .notify-me span {
    vertical-align: top;
}

.notify-me input {
    margin-top: 0.4ex;
}
```

(Try to avoid, fixed-pixel margins/padding, as these will more quickly bust when the user changes font sizes.)